# How to get a number of online members?

Tags: discord, python-3.7, discord.py

I have a command that counts members and bots and outputs them separately. I would then like to output the number of online users. Is this possible?

This command gets member and bot count

```
if message.content.startswith('<count'):    
        membersInServer = message.guild.members
        channel = message.channel
        # Filter to the list, returns a list of bot-members
        botsInServer = list(filter(filterOnlyBots, membersInServer))
        botsInServerCount = len(botsInServer)
        # (Total Member count - bot count) = Total user count
        usersInServerCount = message.guild.member_count - botsInServerCount
        msg = discord.Embed(title="Amount of Human Members in this Discord:", description=usersInServerCount, color=0x00FD00)
        msg.add_field(name="Amount of Bot Users in this Discord:",value=botsInServerCount, inline=False)
        await channel.send(embed=msg)
def filterOnlyBots(member):
    return member.bot
```

I've tried client.member.status and that just returns Online

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each [Member has a status property](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=member#discord.Member.status), which you can use it to check if the [status is offline](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=member#discord.Status.offline) or not.
You can then filter your `membersInServer` by offline status.

```
        onlineMembersInServer = list(filter(filterOnlyOnlineMembers, membersInServer))

        onlineMembersCount = len(onlineMembersInServer)

# Somewhere...
def filterOnlyOnlineMembers(member):
    return member.status != 'offline'
```

Note that it count online users and bots
 If you want to filter to only online users, you can change the filter to this:

```
# Set the filter to be a non-offline member, and the member not being a bot.
def filterOnlyOnlineMembers(member):
    return member.status != 'offline' and not member.bot
```

Note that this might have performance issues if the server is large.

#### Edit

As @Patrick Haugh mentioned, you can make this into a 1-liner

```
sum(member.status!=discord.Status.offline and not member.bot for member in message.guild.members)
```

Comment: I'm getting a `return member.status != member.status.offline
AttributeError: '_EnumValue_Status' object has no attribute 'offline'` error when I try that. And since Im already assigning `botsInServerCount = len(botsInServer)` then that leaves `onlineMembersCount = len(botsInServer)` assigned but not used.

Comment: Edited my answer. Apparently `Status` was a class, not an enum. Also, I should have done `len(onlineMembersInServer)` to count the number of online members in server, not `len(botsInServer)`

Comment: `return member.status != 'offline' && !member.bot` had to be changed to `return member.status != 'offline' and member.status != member.bot` or else I received invalid syntax. nevertheless, it returns total user count lol. even when using `return member.status != 'offline'`

Comment: The invalid syntax was due to me using `&&` instead of `and` keyword, that was my bad. `member.status != member.bot` should be `!member.bot` instead, or `member.bot == false`. Finally, make sure you are using the function to filter when filtering.

Comment: changing it to `member.bot == False` helped but still returning all non bot user count. I put this in the spot the other code you helped me with is. the `def filterOnlyOnlineMembers(member):` is at the bottom along with `def filterOnlyBots(member):`

Comment: You can do this in a single step with something like `sum(member.status==discord.Status.online and not member.bot for member in message.guild.members)`

Comment: @PatrickHaugh So it's outputting 2490 but the dyno.gg bot is saying the online member count is 4528. Is it subtracting something it shouldn't? This is where it's placed `msg.add_field(name="Online:",value=sum(member.status==discord.Status.online and not member.bot for member in message.guild.members), inline=False)`

Comment: @BrandonWeeks `member.status==discord.Status.online` will make it so that it only count users with online status. (Exclusive of 'Idle' or 'Do No Disturb'). Use `member.status != discord.Status.offline` instead.

Comment: @Kaynn Thank you, that did it. You've been so helpful for many of my issues, with your guidance Im able to troubleshoot other issues I was having and resolve them.