# How the I check how many members are online discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

This code is trying to check how many members are online and offline however it comes up with an error message that says guilds cannot be iterated. If the code would work it would send a message with the number of members and how many are online and offline any help would be appreciated.

```
count1=0
count2=0
  
@client.command()
async def stats(ctx):
        
        for member in ctx.guild:
          if member.status == status.online:
           count1 = +1
          else:
            count2 = +1
        embed = discord.Embed(title=ctx.guild.name+"Stats", color=0x000)
        embed.add_field(name="Member Count", value=ctx.guild.member_count)
        embed.add_field(name="Online", value="f'{coun1}' :green_circle:", inline=True)
        embed.add_field(name="Offline", value ="f'{count2}' :red_circle:", inline = True)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57370231/how-to-get-a-number-of-online-members

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I looped through all the members from the guild and added them to the `online_members` list or `offline_members` list and stored nicknames for all users (this way you can use it later if you would like to make some type of list of users). Also, I used `discord.Status.offline` instead of `online` because Discord has a few other status types and some users wouldn't be counted ([list of all status types](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?%20status#discord.Status)).

**My code (with lists of members):**

```py
@client.command()
async def stats(ctx):
    online_members = []
    offline_members = []
    for member in ctx.guild.members:
        if member.status is not discord.Status.offline:
            online_members.append(member.name)
        else:
            offline_members.append(member.name)

    embed = discord.Embed(title=f'"{ctx.guild.name}" Stats', color=0x000)
    embed.add_field(name="Member Count", value=ctx.guild.member_count)
    embed.add_field(name="Online", value=f'{len(online_members)} :green_circle:', inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="Offline", value =f'{len(offline_members)} :red_circle:', inline = True)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

---

**If you prefer to use your code:**

```py
@client.command()
async def stats(ctx):
    count=0 #put these at the beginning of your command so it will reset every time, otherwise, your starting number would be the sum of all earlier commands
    for member in ctx.guild.members: #you forgot to get members
        if member.status != discord.Status.offline:
            count += 1 #you can't use "= +1" - "+= 1" is correct
    
    all_users = ctx.guild.member_count
    embed = discord.Embed(title=f'**{ctx.guild.name}** "Stats"', color=0x000)
    embed.add_field(name="Member Count", value=all_users)
    embed.add_field(name="Online", value=f'"{count}" :green_circle:', inline=True) #your "f" was in wrong place
    embed.add_field(name="Offline", value =f'"{all_users - count}" :red_circle:', inline = True)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

**Remember to enable `intents.members` and `intents.presences`!**

Answer (score 1):

A online member status can be dnd, idle or streaming:

```py
@client.command()
async def stats(ctx):
        count = 0
        for member in ctx.guild.members:  # .members was added
          if member.status != status.oflline:
            count =+ 1
        embed = discord.Embed(title=ctx.guild.name+"Stats", color=0x000)
        embed.add_field(name="Member Count", value=ctx.guild.member_count)
        embed.add_field(name="Online", value="f'{count}' :green_circle:", inline=True)
        embed.add_field(name="Offline", value ="f'{ctx.guild.member_count - count}' :red_circle:", inline = True)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```